# Surfaces of general type with $q=1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $X$ be a smooth projective connected surface of general type over $\mathbb{C}$ with $q(X) = 1$, where $q(X) = \mathrm{h}^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$.
Let $E$ be the Albanese variety of $X$, and let $X\to E$ be the Albanese map (having fixed a point). Let $0$ be a closed point of $E$.

> > Let $F$ be the scheme-theoretic fibre over $0$. Does $F$ have an irreducible *reduced* component? That is, does $F$ have an irreducible component of multiplicity one?

Of course, for a general $0$, the fiber $F$ is smooth. I am wondering whether the Albanese map has a multiple fibre or not.

Comment: It may certainly happen. Take an Enriques surface $S$; it admits an elliptic fibration $S\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ with 2 double fibers, say above $0$ and $1$. Now take a double cover $\pi :E\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ branched along 4 points $\neq 0,1$, and let $T$ be the pull back of $S$ by $\pi $; its Albanese map  is the projection $p:T\rightarrow E$ with 4 double fibers. Then let  $\rho :X\rightarrow T$ be a double covering branched along a smooth, ample curve in $T$, transversal to the double fibers. Its Albanese map $p\circ \rho $  still has 4 double fibers.

Comment: @abx That's a nice example, thank you! But I am wondering whether this *always* happens. (I think I phrased the question in a confusing manner. My apologies.) Basically, given a surface of general type $X$ with $q=1$, my question is whether we can  prove that  $X\to Alb(X)$ has a multiple fibre.

Comment: No, of course it does not happen always

Comment: How can I find an example of a surface with $q=1$ such that $X\to \mathrm{Alb}(X)$ has no multiple fibres? If I start with one of your examples, I could consider ramified coverings of $X$, but I fear this might increase $q$...

Comment: For instance, Cartwright-Steger surface (which has $p_g=q=1$, $K^2=9$) has the property you want. See the main theorem here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.4137.pdf

Comment: CS surface is rigid. Morally, one expects that, one the surface is not rigid,  the "general" element in moduli has reduced Albanese fibres.

Comment: You can construct examples where the Albanese fibres have multiple components but also contains components of multiplicity one by considering a variation of the isogenous constructions, where $G$ is allowed to have isolated fixed points on the product. Look at my paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0703066.pdf and at the other related papers of mine on the arXiv.

Comment: Beautiful...Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find plenty of examples with multiple Albanese fibres by considering surfaces *isogenous to a product*, namely of the form $S=(C \times F)/G$, where $G$ is a finite group acting faithfully on the smooth curves $C$, $F$ and whose diagonal action on the product is free.

For an explicit situation, you can look at Corollary 2.5 of my paper

*[On surfaces of general type with $p_g=q=1$ isogenous to a product of curves](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927870801948676)*, Communications in Algebra **36** (2008), no. 6, 2023-2053, [arXiv:math/0601063](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0601063.pdf).